# Creating a generic interface for a class when the generic type depends on where its getting called from

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I am attempting to create a generic interface that can be implemented by a class who needs to be able to return EITHER a List of type Class1 OR Class2.  I have not been able to get this working because I need to pass in the IRules generic type and if I pass in ClassAbstract I run into the problem below(a very short generic example of what I am really dealing with) where one of the properties is only one of the derived types and not on the base type.

I am not sure how I can get this working the way I want to--basically in that section I can check the type of list and then specify what to do but the issue is that because I am passing in ClassAbstract as the generic parameter this isn't going to work either...is there a way to get this working properly without having to specify the interface type because I don't actually know whether it will be a List of Class1 or a List of Class2 and its based on where it is getting called from?  I obviously could duplicate the code and just use  once method for each class type but its a lot of code and I don't think this should be that hard to do what I want to do but maybe I am wrong...

```
public interface IRules<T> {
List<T>GetAdditionalPropRules(List<T> list1);
List<T>SetAdditionalPropRules(List<T> list1);
}

public ClassAbstract {
  public string NAME {get;set;}
  public string AGE {get;set;}
}

public class Class1: ClassAbstract {
  public string JOB {get;set;}
}

public class Class2: ClassAbstract {

}

public class Rules MyProperties: IRules<ClassAbstract>{ **<--- I Want this to be able to accept either Class1 or Class2**
  public List<ClassAbstract> SetAdditionalPropRules(List<ClassAbstract> myList) {
    foreach(dynamic item in myList) {
      if(item.NAME == "Joe") {
        myList.Add(new ClassAbstract {
          AGE = 30,
          JOB = "Tester" **<--- ISSUE RIGHT HERE -- ClassAbstract Does not have property JOB**
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: You are mixing up generics with `dynamic`. They represent quite contrary concepts. I strongly discourage you from such solution.

Comment: At `ISSUE RIGHT HERE`, you can just add a `new Class1()`. Since both `Class1` and `Class2` inherit `ClassAbstract`, they're _both_ `ClassAbstract`s.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but `var` in place of `dynamic` in the `foreach` loop would be more correct.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The method you are trying to write operates on a `List<ClassAbstract>`. It is not clear why every person whose name is `"Joe"` is necessarily a `"Tester"`. That said, if you want to set the `JOB` property, and that property is present only in the `Class1` class, then of course you need to create a new instance of `Class1`. So, why not do that? Why are you using `new ClassAbstract` instead of `new Class1`? Please improve your question so it makes sense.

Comment: It seems like you'd like `SetAdditionalPropRules` to set the `JOB` property if it receives a  `Class1`. What do you want to do if it's a `Class2`? If it is supposed to do something different, it isn't generic. A generic method is for when you do the same thing to a variety of types, and in this case you want to do something different depending on the type.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But the code you provided does not compile because of writing errors or missing items impossible to interpret. Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, consider reading the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, consider reading the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. Your question has a low quality. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, consider reading the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*.

Answer (score 0):

Is that can help you?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{

  static partial class Program
  {
```

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Test();
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("End.");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

```
    static void Test()
    {
      var rules = new RulesMyProperties();
      var list = new List<ClassAbstract>();
      list.Add(new Class1 { NAME = "Joe", AGE = 20 });
      list.Add(new Class2 { NAME = "Joe", AGE = 25 });
      list.Add(new Class1 { NAME = "John", AGE = 30 });
      list.Add(new Class2 { NAME = "John", AGE = 35 });
      Action print = () =>
      {
        foreach ( var item in list )
        {
          Console.Write($"{item.NAME} / {item.GetType().Name} : {item.AGE}");
          if ( item is Class1 )
            Console.Write($" ({((Class1)item).JOB})");
          Console.WriteLine();
        }
      };
      print();
      rules.SetAdditionalPropRules(list);
      Console.WriteLine();
      print();
    }
```

```
  }
```

```
  public class RulesMyProperties : IRules<ClassAbstract>
  {

    public List<ClassAbstract> SetAdditionalPropRules(List<ClassAbstract> myList)
    {
      foreach ( var item in myList.ToList() )
      {
        if ( item != null )
          if ( item.NAME == "Joe" )
          {
            if ( item is Class1 )
            {
              ( item as Class1 ).AGE = 30;
              ( item as Class1 ).JOB = "Tester";
            }
            else
            {
              myList.Remove(item);
              myList.Add(new Class1
              {
                NAME = "Joe",
                AGE = 30,
                JOB = "Tester"
              });
            }
            break;
          }
      }
      return myList;
    }

    public List<ClassAbstract> GetAdditionalPropRules(List<ClassAbstract> list1)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

  }
```

```
  public interface IRules<T>
  {
    List<T> GetAdditionalPropRules(List<T> list1);
    List<T> SetAdditionalPropRules(List<T> list1);
  }
```

```
  public class ClassAbstract
  {
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public int AGE { get; set; }
  }
```

```
  public class Class1 : ClassAbstract
  {
    public string JOB { get; set; }
  }
```

```
  public class Class2 : ClassAbstract
  {

  }
```

```
}
```

Output:

```
Joe / Class1 : 20 ()
Joe / Class2 : 25
John / Class1 : 30 ()
John / Class2 : 35

Joe / Class1 : 30 (Tester)
Joe / Class2 : 25
John / Class1 : 30 ()
John / Class2 : 35
```

Comment: Doesn't work...."Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ClassAbstract>' to 'Class1' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion".  I will just give up on this way of doing it...probably not a good idea I just hate duplicating this much code because of literally 2 lines.

Comment: It must work. Answer updated with full file code and test. I took your code to do it but you should refactor it and set the RulesMyProperties class as static since it is a helper, it seems.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps, like this? - if you base your Class1 and Class2 on some interface:

```
     interface IClassAbsract
         {
             string Name { get; set; }
             string Age { get; set; }
         }
         public class Class1: IClassAbsract
         {
             public string Name { get; set; }
             public string Age { get; set; }
         }
         public class Class2 : IClassAbsract
         {
             public string Name { get; set; }
             public string Age { get; set; }
         }

         public class ListRule
         {
             public List<IClassAbsract> List { get; set; } = new List<IClassAbsract>();
         }
```

then, later, those can be used like this:

```
            ...
     ...
     //populate list with testing instances
     var list = new ListRule();
     var c1 = new Class1() { Name = "Class #1", Age = "11" };
     list.List.Add(c1);

     var c2 = new Class2() { Name = "Class #2", Age = "22" };
     list.List.Add(c2);

     ...
     //then, get only certain types, and populate second list "myList": for example, pull only of type Class1:
     public  void Test2(List<IClassAbsract> list)
     {
             if (list == null || !list.Any())
             {
                     throw new System.ArgumentNullException("empty");
             }
             //pull only of type Class1:
             List<IClassAbsract> myList = new List<IClassAbsract>();
             myList.AddRange(list
                    .Where(e => e is Class1)
                     .Select(e => new Class1() { Age = e.Age, Name = "Joe" })
                     .ToList()
             );
    }
```